# Exception as default value of Spring @Value()

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I'm new to Java/Spring. I need to read some value from config but if it doesn't exist it should fails. For now I have the following code:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Value("${some.property:#{null}}")
    private String someProperty;

    public void someMethod() throws Exception {
        if (someProperty == null) throw new AopConfigException("The property must be set");
    }

}
```

It works fine but I need to add additional `if` block. Could I write something like that?

```
@Value("${some.property:#{throw new AopConfigException(\"The property must be set\")}}")
private String someProperty;
```

or

```
@Value("${some.property:#{throwException()}}")
private String someProperty;

private static void throwException() {
    throw new AopConfigException("The property must be set");
}
```

to fail immediately

**Upd:**
If I don't use some default value as suggested below then it still doesn't fail for me. I don't have `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:

[image]

Comment: just use @Value("${some.property}") instead of @Value("${some.property:#{null}}")

Comment: spring will look for the value, and if it is not there, it will throw an exception

Comment: It returns "${some.property}" instead of exception for me

Comment: What is the value of  `importDataPath`, if the property is set? In order for the property replacement to work you need to configure a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean.

Comment: @dpr `${import.data.path}` as demonstrated on screenshot

Comment: Where do you keep your properties?

Comment: @dpr *.properties file which is included by `@PropertySource` annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the property replacement to work you will need to add a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean to your configuration like this ([example taken from here](http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)):

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
  final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  // add your property files below
  final Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]{new ClassPathResource("foo.properties")};
  pspc.setLocations( resources );
  // this will make the replacement fail, if property is not known
  pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false); 
  return pspc;
}
```

If you already configure your property sources with `@PropertySource` annotations you should be able to omit adding the resources to the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` manually as it should pickup values from the spring environment automatically.

Once this bean is in place simply use

```
@Value("${data.import.path}")
```

without default (as already mentioned in the other answers) and initialization of your application will fail at a very early stage.

Comment: While this also would works it sets the required constraint for all referenced values. It might be helpful in some use cases.

Comment: Yes, of course. If you don't want an `Exception` for some properties you can simply provide defaults where needed.

Comment: So the solution is `pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);`?

Comment: I think It's `false` by default. I just added it to make this setting explicit. But yes, it should work as desired, if this setting is `false` and you have the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean configured. Note that the bean method for the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is `static`. This is mandatory for this bean to be wired correctly.

Comment: @Serg046, and? Did this solve your problem? Our do you have additional issues?

Comment: @dpr, sorry I'll check it during 2 hours, thank you for your answer

Comment: @Serg046, and? Did this solve your problem? Our do you have additional issues?

Comment: @dpr sorry for delay, I don't have this bean configured. So I think I use default parameters then. What should I try, configure this bean?

Comment: @Serg046, yes. Add this bean to your configuration class as described above.

Comment: @dpr, yep, it works! Thank you. I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` and `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'data.import.path' in value "${data.import.path}"`. Do you know how can I give you bounty, maybe we can ask moderator?

Comment: @Serg046, the bounty period has ended and the bounty is lost. There is nothing you can do about it. But thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 9):

@Value is required by default. So, just use

```
@Value("${some.property}")
```

instead of

```
@Value("${some.property:#{null}}")
```

so if the property doesn't exist, your application fails to start with an exception like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'invalid.value' in value "${invalid.value}"
```

**Update:** If you want to have a key and that can be empty like this:

```
some.property=
```

and you want to throw exception if that property is empty, then use `@PostConstruct` as below:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void validateValue() {
        if (someProperty.isEmpty()) {
            throw new MyNiceException("error");
        }
    }
```

**More update:** and if you want to have null initialized in case if there is no registry for key as

```
    @Value("${some.property:#{null}}")
    private String someProperty;
```

then do like this:

```
        @PostConstruct
        public void validateValue() {
            if (someProperty == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It returns "${some.property}" instead of exception for me

Comment: Serg046, may be you are importing @Value from lombok?

Comment: import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

Comment: it should fail with exception something like this `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'invalid.value' in value "${invalid.value}"
` i just did on my machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174822/discussion-between-serg046-and-yogen-rai).

Comment: @Serg046 did you ever figure out why spring was returning the key instead of throwing a missing exception?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot do that by just using the `@Value` annotation. However, you can check check if a certain property is set by reading the value using the spring environment. This would throw an `IllegalStateException` if the value is not set.

So, for example if you have the environment variable, e.g.:

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment env;
```

Then you can initialise the value by calling the method `getRequiredProperty`:

```
<T> T getRequiredProperty(java.lang.String key, java.lang.Class<T> targetType) 
      throws java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

So for your use case you would initialise your bean like this:

```
@Bean
public SomeClass someClass () {

  String someProperty = env.getRequiredProperty ("some.property");

  return new SomeClass (someProperty);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this way. It requires ConfigurableEnvironment. However it's a workable solution that's why I upvoted you. But anyways it's pretty interesting why other people said that it is possible, downvoted but didn't provide workable solution xD

Answer (score 0):

Just verify in post construct to guarantee it running as soon as the bean was created:

```
@PostConstruct
private static void throwException() {
  if (someProperty == null) {
    throw new AopConfigException("The property must be set");
  }
}
```

Comment: Then I still need to have two condition checks. The first one is for `null`, the second one to throw an exception.
Maybe `Spring` contains something like `@RequiredValue()` instead of `@Value()`?

Comment: @Serg046 `@Value` *is* required by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't give a default value to your property like 
`@Value("${some.property}")`

> And in case the property is not set spring will through an exception and you are done right.

Comment: Please take a look on my screenshot in the updated question